# In C++, how can I programmatically detect the reverse scrolling setting on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Specifically I want to determine the state of the Windows setting for Mouse / Touchpad -> "Reverse scrolling direction" (which defaults to off). Ideally this would be extracted from the event data but a falling back to querying the current OS state would be sufficient. I wasn't able to find either solution in the MSDN documentation.

Note: That setting is only available in the mouse / trackpad settings on Windows 8 or Windows 10 and only if you have a precise scrolling device (like a Surface Pro 3).

Comment: Probably something in [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or maybe some other Windows API `Get???` function

Comment: I'm dumb - more likely you need the [Windows API registry functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and to know which registry key, of course.

Comment: May I ask why you care? your window will scroll correctly and you should only concern yourself with when scroll position changes.

Comment: For my specific case, I need to scroll the same direction regardless of the inversion setting.  The scrolling is handled by custom control that needs* to go the same direction regardless of the inversion state. *Needs to: As in I was instructed to make it do that.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know of a few "standard" or "official" approaches to getting system information.

- [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If none of these work and you can't find info in MSDN, then @Steve314's suggestion of checking the registry is probably the way to go.  One approach to identifying the correct registry key:

1. Open the Mouse / Touchpad control panel and get ready to change the setting.
2. Download and run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx).
3. Change the setting in the Mouse / Touchpad control panel.
4. Search for `RegSetValue` calls in Process Monitor's output to try and find the one that corresponds to the setting you care about.

Comment: That's a great generic process to find the modified registry key and then I'll use Steve314's registry api pointer to access the value.  I'll try that route.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find the scrolling direction via the other suggestions, but I was able to find the registry key using the Process Monitor suggestion.  The registry key is:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\ScrollDirection

Thanks!